# how to change a property of the first child

Tags: javascript, css, parent-child

I am able to change the background-color of this element:

```
<div onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='blue'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='red'" style="background-color:green; width:100px; height:40px;">
</div>
```

But I want to change the color of the first child, which I assumed should work like this:

```
<div onmouseover="this.firstChild.style.backgroundColor='blue'" onmouseout="this.firstChild.style.backgroundColor='red'" style="background-color:green; width:100px; height:40px;">

  <div style="background-color:white; height:10px; width:10px; margin:20px;">This is the first child, I think.</div>

</div>
```

But it does not work. What is wrong? How can I change the style of the firstChild?

PS: I later want to use display=block and none and some other propertys (not just style) for the child. The color was just for testing.

Comment: Please stop using inline CSS/JavaScript. This is not how software is written anymore.

Comment: /agree with @meagar. also, please use a javascript library or framework like jquery

Comment: @Populus: Why do you recommend a JavaScript library? You have no way of knowing if the situation calls for one.

Comment: @thesystem Lol but a Javascript library solves everything! Especially for one tiny problem you have. It's so worth it. All 30-100Kb :)

Comment: a javascript library handles the horrible need to make javascript compatible with various browsers *ahem*IE*ahem*. If you think jQuery may be a bit heavy, you can consider using something like underscore...

Comment: @Populus True, but compatibility has nothing to do with this specific problem. It's the understanding of what `firstChild` holds in this situation. And obviously, there's a fairly simple solution (thanks to the answers) that shouldn't have cross-browser problems...and doesn't require a library.

Comment: @Populus: No need to spread FUD. Incompatibilities are very often easily solved without loading a large abstraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use `.firstElementChild`, or you'd need to get rid of the formatting whitespace. That whitespace becomes a text node, which is the `.firstChild`.

The `.firstElementChild` property isn't supported by some older browsers, so if you're supporting those, you'd need to shim it with a function.

---

```
<div onmouseover="changeColor(this, 'blue')" onmouseout="changeColor(this, 'red')" style="background-color:green; width:100px; height:40px;">

  <div style="background-color:white; height:10px; width:10px; margin:20px;">This is the first child, I think.</div>

</div>
```

---

```
function changeColor(el, color) {
    firstElemChild(el).style.backgroundColor=color;
}
function firstElemChild(el) {
    if (el.firstElementChild)
        return el.firstElementChild;

    el = el.firstChild

    while (el && el.nodeType !== 1)
        el = el.nextSibling;

    return el;
}
```

Comment: Or loop through the children elements and find the first one that isn't a text node?

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I like both answers and don’t know which one to accept.

Comment: @erik: Go ahead and accept the other one. It really doesn't matter to me. But be aware that some IE versions have a quirk with `.children` in that it'll include comment nodes. Not an issue if there are no HTML comments. And FF3 didn't support it, but that's pretty much a non-issue at this point. For more compatibility info, visit http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html

Answer (score 4):

As "the system" mentioned, you are targeting a text node rather than an element node. Try using `children[0]` instead of `firstChild`.

[jFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rfpLS/)

Comment: Browser compatibility for `children` is list here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.children